# how to use continue keyword with a label

Tags: java, continue

There is an error which says continue cannot be used outside the block.I have labelled Mult_search and i want the program to run from the label if the if condition(temp11==value)
were to be true.
Please tell me how to rectify this error or suggest me any other method!

```
Mult_search:
     {
        if(l1!=(mul) && re1!=0)
        {
            temp11=(int)mult[l1][0];
            Iterator it4 = a1.iterator();
            while(it4.hasNext())
            {
                Integer value=(Integer)it4.next();
                if(temp11==value)
                {
                    l1++;
                    continue Mult_search;
                }

            }
            for(x=0;x<nodes;x++)
            {
                if(parent[x][0]==temp11)
                    l=x;
            }
        }
     }
```

Comment: Java? Please tag the language

Comment: You are in a bad need of a Java: First Steps tutorial.

Comment: no offence..if possible jot down the mistake.Thanks for your advice @MarkoTopolnik

Comment: Only a flow control statement may be the target of a label.

Answer (score 0):

In Java labels can be put only before a `for`, `while` and `do...while` loop. And "before" means precisely before as in

```
MY_LABEL: 
while(condition){
    body();
    if( otherCondition )
        continue MY_LABEL;
}
```

In your case the label just sticks to Joe Random Block. This is not allowed because neither `break` nor `continue` are intended as a substitute for `goto`.